# Can son/wife stop an addict from selling family property in India?

Tags: india, property

If a person (not a senior citizen) is addicted and trying to sell off his farming land (which has been inherited from his grandfather and later through his father) without the consent his wife and children, is there anything that can be done to stop this transaction?

Comment: You can claim property rights and claim your portions. I don't think you can stop him from selling his portion. He is entitled to his portion.

Comment: This will be a comment only as I am not well versed in Indian law but one avenue elsewhere would be placing the person under legal guardianship which would remove his right to enter into binding agreements.

Comment: In other jurisdictions (I'm thinking on Spain) a prodigal person can be put under legal guardianship only in the extent needed to supply aliment to the  people he is obliged to do so.

Answer (score 2):

No. As long as it is owned by him he is free to do as he likes. The wife / children do not have any claims as it is ancestral property and they can have a claim only after his demise. Until then, he is free to do as he likes legally.